# (android) How to send data from DialogFragment to Activity?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

In MainActivity, when i click button `DialogFragment` displays.

I want to send the data I got from the `DialogFragment`.

`DialogFragment`'consist of `RecyclerView`. Each item consists of `TextView`

I succeeded to get datas. When i click `save button` datas must be sent to the `Activity`.

But i don't know how to send them to Activity.

`Intent` must uses `startAcitivity` so it is unsuitable.

How to send data 'DialogFragment' to 'Activity'?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way would be to :

- add a method to your activity (MyAcitivity.class)
  void myMethod(Mydata data)...
- from your dialog when you want send data, (MyActivity)getActivity().myMethod(data)

That's all.

Comment: Thank you. However how about using a `interface`?
I mean, define interface in DialogFragment and implement interface's method in MainActivity. and then call the implemented method.
is this way inefficient?

Comment: Can do too. Define an interface in your fragment. Then implement it in your activity. Then if your interface is implemented by your activity, doesn't need to register it to your fragment, can access it by ((my interface)getActivity).myInterfaceMethod(data).

Comment: If your implemented method is an anonymous method from your activity, you gonna have to register it to your fragment. When you create your fragment, you can pass this anonymous method, but you gonna have to manage the configuration change (rotation)